Critical GRUB error and SSSD dependency failures - required Ubuntu reinstallation
I encountered a critical issue with Ubuntu where I could only access the GRUB terminal (v2.12 in BIOS mode). On boot, multiple dependency failures appeared with messages like:
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-nss.socket - SSSD NSS Service responder socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-autofs.socket - SSSD Autofs Service responder socket

Additional services (pac, pam-priv, pam, ssh, sudo) also displayed dependency failures. Using a live Linux USB, I attempted numerous solutions through the console, including updating, uninstalling, reinstalling, and even disabling services from both the OS and boot configurations. Unfortunately, none of these approaches resolved the issue. Due to these persistent errors and lack of a viable solution I ultimately had to perform a full reinstallation of Ubuntu.
If anyone knows of an alternative solution for this type of critical dependency failure involving SSSD and GRUB boot errors, any guidance would be greatly appreciated to avoid a full reinstall in the future.

